# Android Hiding the status bar after exiting

Tags: android, user-interface, statusbar

So I have a code that hides the status bar but the only problem is that if I went to the homepage and then reopen the application (Still running) the status bar shows up. Also, when I press the option button (The button below), it shows the status bar. Is there a way to disable the option button and hide the status bar when reopening the running application?

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions)
```

Comment: For option button problem try my solution.

Comment: Oh, I meant, I just don't want the option button to show anything like showing the "settings" tab and the status bar not to show too. I'll try that later. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it didn't work. When I pressed the option button, the status bar showed up and the settings tab also showed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well its happening because when your activity pause the `Statusbar` gets visible so you need hide the `Statusbar` in `onResume`of your activity, something like this example:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions)
}
```

Now if you resume the app it will `Statusbar` will stay hidden.

Comment: Oh thank you :). I just have one more problem. When I press the option button on the phone, the status bar shows up. Is there a way to disable the option button which is located at the bottom of the phone?

Comment: you talking about the options button near home and back button in bottom?

Comment: Oh, yup. I just realized that when I try to reopen the application.

Answer (score 1):

**android manifest**

select / set **theme** as `NoActionBar`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Note**

**If you only wants for `single activity` then,**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Now Remove this from your `MainActivity.java`,**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: No Title bar, what does that do? Also, it says No Action Bar?

Comment: It worked about the tab not showing but when I pressed the options button multiple times, the status bar showed.

Comment: have you removed `onCreateOptionsMenu` from your activity

Comment: Yup. If I pressed it twice on the first opening, it shows. But later on, it's fixed. The only problem is that if I pressed it twice after opening the application.

Comment: Remove menu.xml from menu folder

Comment: I removed it and still same. :/ Maybe, it's inevitable. Is there a way to like hide it when it shows up?

Comment: I am not getting this issue. On which device are you working???

Tested on 1. Lenovo K3 Note(6.0)  2. Micromax A350(4.4.2)

Comment: Android Lenovo A369i

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the notification bar in the `onCreate` and `onResume` method works for me:

```
    public override fun onCreate(
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Hide the status bar
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // Hide the status bar
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    }
```